# Write a Scalar to CSV (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, export-to-csv

I'm generating a number of test files iteratively, the process derives a 0, 1 or 2 dimensional numpy array, then writes that array to CSV, at least that's the intent.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

My code (expectedly) fails when the output is zero-dimensional (scalar):

```
for key in testfiles:
    tname = key + ".csv"
    np.savetxt(tname, testfiles[key], delimiter=",",newline=';',fmt='%0.15f')
```

Comment: The documentation explicitly mentions "X: 1D or 2D array_like". Probably best to turn the scalar into a 1D 1-element array. `np.atleast_1d` will be of use here.

Comment: Exactly the tidbit i was missing, thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to ensure that your input is not a scalar in numpy. For example, you could use [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
arr = np.array(testfiles[key], ndmin=1, copy=False)
```

Another option is [`np.atleast_1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html):

```
arr = np.atleast_1d(testfiles[key])
```

Both options will attempt to make an object without copying the data. In both cases, pass `arr` to [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) instead of `testfiles[key]`.